# PHP: How do I figure out where file_put_contents is going to save a file?

Tags: php, path

If I just use file_put_contents('file.txt', $stuff), how do I determine where that's going to save? In some files it saves to a completely different folder.

Comment: Just a crazy thought: maybe give it a complete path then?

Comment: If you don't specify a full path, it would save the file in the current working directory (CWD). This is usually the directory of the file that was originally loaded (not included/required). You can see the CWD with [getcwd()](http://php.net/getcwd).

Comment: @Machavity The point is to not have to type or copy and paste an absolute path especially when it's crazy long. I could use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] but the point of the question was to figure out where file_put_contents thought it was when it went to write.

@ jonathan-kuhn Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

log/echo both `$stuff` and `getcwd()`. If you don't want to analyse such pairs, use [`realpath()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php)

Comment: Thanks, this seems to get the results I expect.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that would like to save your files in the file_folder name. Firstly, by `chdir('file_folder');` you easily change the default path of `file_put_contents` function. Obviously, the below simple example helps cognition of it.

```
chdir('file_folder');
file_put_contents('file.txt', $stuff)
```